# Is there any Jenkins plugin for pylint results?

Tags: jenkins-plugins, python

I have Pipeline which run Jenkinsfile. one of the stage is pylint:

```
python -m pylint --rcfile=.pylintrc --exit-zero ${MODULE} > ${WORKSPACE}/testreport/pylint.log
```

I know there was used to be violations plugin which is now deprecated. is there any alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jenkins accepts [JUnit-formatted test results with the JUnit plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/junit/), so you could try [pylint-junit](https://pypi.org/project/pylint-junit/) to output JUnit-formatted results (I have not tried this myself).

Also it looks like [a very similar question was asked and answered over on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41875412/use-pylint-on-jenkins-with-warnings-plugin-and-pipleine).

Comment: I ran it. Any idea why using this plugin doesn't print the score like in the `log`: `Your code has been rated at 9.79/10`

Comment: Because you use XML format output. Thus the plain text `Your code...` makes XML malformed.